# Series expansion def

Tags: analysis

I have this proposition-definition in my lecture that I did not understand:

*let $x\in I$ and $n \in \mathbb{N} $. A function $f \in \mathbb{R}^I$ has a series expansion of order $n$ near $x$ if there exists $a_0, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{I-x}$ such that $\lim \limits_{\delta \to 0} \epsilon(\delta)= 0$ and $$\forall \delta \in I-x, \quad f(x+\delta)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\delta^k+\delta^k\epsilon(\delta)$$*

What I understood is that $f$ is a sum of polynomials and I know that $\delta$ represent a small value close to $x$ and $\epsilon$ any small value.
What I speculated from reading my notes again is that $a_k\delta^k$ is getting closer to $0$ as $n$ increases until reaching $x$. As for the $\delta^k\epsilon(\delta)$ part, I could not come up to understand it on my own.

Could someone please explain to me how this proposition-definition works and correct me if I made any errors in my reasoning (aka me trying to understand)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is "$I$" here? $[0,1]$?

Comment: What the definition is saying is that there is a degree $n$ polynomial $P(t)$ such that the function $g(t) = \frac{f(x + t) - P(t)}{t^n}$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to 0} g(t) = 0$. That is, the failure of $f(x + t)$ to match to polynomial $P(t)$ goes to $0$ faster than $t^n$, which indicates that $P(t)$ is in this sense, the $n$-degree polynomial that most closely matches $f$. The definition makes the somewhat odd notational choice of calling the local variable $t$ by $\delta$ and the difference function $g(t)$ by $\epsilon(\delta)$.

Comment: Our textbook just says an interval  ""...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: "An interval" is an appropriate definition. Not defining it at all is inappropriate.

Comment: ok ok thank you very much!!